# Hadoop streaming failed with java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have written a map only python map-reduce job which accepts data from standard input and process it to produce some output. It works fine when executed locally. However, when I am trying to execute it using hadoop I get file not found exception.  Its not able to locate the mapper.py file. Also, here is the command that I use to run the script :

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-1.1.1.jar -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 -file "$PWD/mapper.py" -mapper "$PWD/mapper.py" -input "relevance/test.txt" -output "relevance/test_output_8.txt"
```

The file test.txt has been copied to HDFS as well.

**Error:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /data1/mapr-hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/***********/job_201405060940_908425/attempt_201405060940_908425_m_000000_0/work/******/mapper.py does not exist.
```

can any one figure out what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the the $PWD from the file path solved the problem. The working command :

hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-1.1.1.jar -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 -file "mapper.py" -mapper "mapper.py" -input "relevance/test.txt" -output "relevance/test_output_8.txt"

Also, make sure the paths are specified withing " " . I came across lot of examples on the web where the examples had the " " missing.